# Confusion around a components pins

Tags: datasheet, packages, pinout

I'm looking to use a RBO40 reverse battery & over voltage protection. I was unable to find the RBO40-40T (with 3 pins) anywhere so had to get RBO40-40G, which is slightly different, it has the middle GND pin cut and the data sheet says this goes to the TAB instead.

I'm not really up on this chip packaging, how am I meant to connect this GND when the TAB is a flat metal surface on the back of the chip?

Data sheet is [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001320.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The middle pin that is cut and the TAB are both shorted to GND. When you are placing the part on PCB create a PCB footprint for the flat surface and connect the pad to ground. This is also used to dissipate heat. The part you have is a SMT part.

[image]

If you are soldering wires, solder the GND wire to the flat TAB. You will find \$D^2PAK\$ package in the attach image below. Like the TO-220 package \$D^2PAK\$ is mostly used in power products.

[image]

If you look at page 5 and page 9 of the datasheet you will see more infomation about the package.

**References:**

- [D2PAK Outline Dimensions](http://www.vishay.com/docs/95046/d2pak.pdf)
- [TO-220 Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220)

Comment: Great, was just confirming this really. I will solder to the tab. Not ideal but ok for a prototype right

Answer (score 4):

Here is an image about the required layout/footprint. It is clearly shows how you should design and solder your component.

[image]

By the way the datasheet holds the answer for your question, always read it in detail. I took this picture from it.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I read that, I just thought that was odd and wanted to check.